# How to stop the Java Auto Upgrade from JDK 17 to JDK 18

Tags: java, java-17, java-18

I am using oracle JDK 17 in my cloud desktop and it is upgrading to oracle JDK 18 automatically. Since we are using Java 17 in our project, I had to reinstall the JDK 17 on every time it is upgrading to JDK 18. I want to turn off the auto update of Java. is there a way to turn off the Auto upgrade of Java 17 to 18.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinstall Oracle JDK-17 but with an additional configuration file.

Create a file named `config.txt`.

*In that file write this line:*

```
AUTO_UPDATE=Disable
```

1. Open your terminal with administrator privileges.
2. Go to the directory where installer is present, using `cd` command.
3. Run this command `installer.exe INSTALLCFG=config.txt`, NOTE: `installer.exe` is the installer file which you have downloaded
4. Install Oracle JDK as normal

Here's more details from official oracle [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/config.html#using_config_file)

Comment: "javacpl.exe" has been removed in the java 11 version. we can't use this command

Comment: @pradeep3009 Here you go